# App icon and Default.png is not working properly in 2G iphone?

Tags: iphone

My app icon of my application is not working in 2g version of the iphone (icon.png). only appear white icon with application name and also problem in default.png. can any one help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application icon image is not appears in the iPhone 2G?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022133/application-icon-image-is-not-appears-in-the-iphone-2g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both file names should start from a capital letter - Icon.png and Default.png.

Comment: @kovpas- both .png file start capital letter only still not working only in 2G but working properly in 3G and 4G

Comment: @sribharanidharan do you install it using XCode?

Comment: @sribharanidharan, sounds weird. You may also check if both files doesn't use interlace (choose None when you save a file in photoshop) - this also could be the reason.

Comment: @kovpas -  thanx for quick comment can you clarify me what you mean to tell in this statement (choose None when you save a file in photoshop)

Comment: @sribharanidharan open an Icon.png file in photoshop, pick save as, you'll see a dialog, where you should pick None.